# Properly remove Oracle ODP.NET dll?

Tags: oracle

I registered the ODP.NET Oracle.DataAccess.dll for x64 by using the x64 Oracle Client's `OraProvCfg` utility:

```
oraprovcfg /action:gac /providerpath:C:/PathToDll/Oracle.DataAccess.dll
```

It added the .dll to:

```
C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/Oracle.DataAccess
```

Now I've uninstalled Oracle client and I'd like to remove this dll.  Is there a proper way to remove it, rather than deleting the folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the proper way is to simply delete it. However, ensure you open GAC folder with Windows Explorer (not the command line or any other File Explorer).

Or check syntax of oraprovcfg, I assume it provides an "remove from GAC" action.

Comment: Official tool from Microsoft ist the gacutil.ext, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ex0ss12c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`oraprovcfg /action:ungac /providerpath:C:/PathToDll/Oracle.DataAccess.dll`

That is the reversal command.